# How to add tap functionality to label using UITapGestureRecognizer in static func

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I need to add tap functionality to `labels` (to open a website) in my app dynamically, I was thinking in create static function inside a `class`. I want to launch the function in any `ViewController` of my app.

I´ve done this using Swift 3:

```
class Launcher {
    static func openWeb(label: UILabel, url: String) {
        func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
            }
        }

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunction))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
        }

    }
}
```

But doesn't work because I'm getting error in `action: #selector(tapFunction)`

**error**: `Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'tapFunction(sender:)'`

If I use this inside a `ViewController` code using `action: #selector(myView.tapFunction)` like the following, works

Inside `viewDidLoad`

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.tapFunction))
mylabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
mylabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Separated function inside `ViewController`

```
func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
        }
    }
```

I want to convert this last code to static function inside my `Class` to call it in any `ViewController`. Thank you

Comment: How are you thinking this is going to be metaphysically possible? A static function is static (i.e. at class level); there is no instance. So what object are we even supposed to be talking to?

Comment: I'm doing similar things with static functions, for example: to assign styles to Outlets and it works fine. Calling MyClass.function() and passing objects as parameter.

Comment: Still, it is far from clear to me what the static-ness of this method even is. It seems to me it's more a UILabel subclass instance method! I'm just trying to suggest a reorientation of thinking here.

Comment: It will not be the right way to do it. But I thought that metaphysically it might be possible. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try resolve it using **extension**

```
extension UILabel {
    func openWeb(url: String) {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunction))
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        openURL(url: url)
    }

    func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        openURL(url: "")
    }

    func openURL(url: String) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: url)!)
        }
    }
}

let label = UILabel()
label.openWeb(url: "123")
```

> To store link into label you can use associations with label object.

Comment: Something is not working... The website is opening when view loads. Without touching anything.

Comment: remove "openURL(url: url)" from "func openWeb(url: String)".
Just configure UITapGestureRecognizer;

"let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapFunction))
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)".

It'll work how you want.
Note: I tried translate your solution on extension way.

Answer (score 2):

A method that is supposed to communicate with an instance cannot be a static / class method. That's what static / class method *means*; it is about the *class* — there is no instance in the story. Thus what you are proposing is impossible, unless you hand the static method the instance it is supposed to talk to.

To me personally, a tappable URL-opening label sounds like a label subclass, and this functionality would then be an instance method of that label.

Comment: Or, as suggested, you could inject it into all labels as an extension. But a label subclass could have a stored URL property, which might suit you better.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are some general problems with your approach. Selectors work by message passing. E.g. with `UITapGestureRecognizer(target:, action:)` The message calling the method (the `action`) is sent to the variable ( the `target`).

When you create a local function, that function is a member of the enclosing function and not the containing class or instance, so your approach categorically cannot work.

Even if it could work, it would also go against OOP and MVC design principals. A `Label` should not be in charge of what happens when it's tapped, just as the title of a book is not in charge of opening the book.

Taking all that into consideration, this is how I would solve your problem:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func addTapGesture(to view: UIView, with selector: Selector) {
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: selector))
    }
}

extension UIApplication {

    func open(urlString: String) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            open(URL(string: urlString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            openURL(URL(string: urlString)!)
        }
    }
}

class YourVC: UIViewController {

    var aLabel: UILabel? = nil

    func addTapGesture() {
        addTapGesture(to: aLabel!, with: #selector(tapGestureActivated))
    }

    func tapGestureActivated(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(urlString: "YourURLHere")
    }
}
```

This abstracts away the boilerplate and is simple at the point of use, while still properly separating out Type responsibilities and using generalized functionality that can be re-used elsewhere.